# Child action http request not showing in network tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two action methods:

```
        public PartialViewResult GetPeopleData(string selectedRole = "All")
        {
            IEnumerable<Person> data = personData;
            if (selectedRole != "All")
            {
                Role selected = (Role)Enum.Parse(typeof(Role), selectedRole);
                data = personData.Where(p => p.Role == selected);
            }
            return PartialView(data);
        }

        public ActionResult GetPeople(string selectedRole = "All")
        {
            return View((object)selectedRole);
        }
```

and the following line in the `GetPeople.cshtml` view:

```
@Html.Action("GetPeopleData", new { selectedRole = Model })
```

The page loads fine, and the `GetPeopleData()` child action method is called and returns a partial view.

However in the Network tab in F12 developer options in Chrome, I can only see the call to `GetPeople()`, there is no call to `GetPeopleData()` even though it stops there on the breakpoint during debug and returns the partial view.

Why can't I see the `GetPeopleData()` HTTP request in the network tab?

Comment: Your view, its layout and any partials are all merged in to one html document on the server before its sent to the view

Comment: ahh of course, thanks for clearing that up.